# Writing a buffer to a PDF in C++

Tags: visual-c++, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to write a buffer into PDF file.is there any method ? i am using c++.

Comment: What kind of data is in the buffer, and how do you want it represented in the PDF?

Comment: suppose i have a string "Hello World" i want to write it in PDF

Answer (score 2):

You need a PDF library for that. There are free and commercial libraries available. If you're looking for a free one look at [LibHaru](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libharu/) and [PDF Creator Pilot](http://www.colorpilot.com/pdflibrary.html).